# The difference between 'HashSet' and 'Set' in Scala?

Tags: scala, set, hashset

I'm very confused by Scala's `HashSet` and `Set` types as they both seem to do the same thing.

- What is the difference between them?
- Is it the same in Java?
- In my reference it says that `HashSet` is an "explicit set class" (as compared to `Set`). What does that mean?

Comment: see also [another version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759913/what-is-the-difference-between-hashset-and-set-and-when-should-each-one), as well as a similar question for [`Map` vs `HashMap`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685236/scala-map-vs-hashmap)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Scala's mutable and immutable `HashSet` implementations are concrete classes which you can instantiate. For example, if you explicitly ask for a new `scala.collection.immutable.HashSet`, you will always get a set which is implemented by a hash trie. There are other set implementations, such as `ListSet`, which uses a list.

`Set` is a [trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/126) which all the set implementations extend (whereas in Java, `Set` is an interface).

`Set` is also a companion object* with an `apply`** method. When you call `Set(...)`, you're calling this factory method and getting a return value which is some kind of `Set`. It might be a `HashSet`, but could be some other implementation. According to [2](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html), the default implementation for an immutable set has special representation for empty set and sets size up to 4. Immutable sets size 5 and above and mutable sets all use hashSet.

---

*In Scala, instead of having static class methods, you can create a singleton `object` with the same name as your class or trait. This is called a companion object, and methods you define on it can be called as `ObjectName.method()`, similar to how you'd call a static method in Java.

**`Set(x)` is syntactic sugar for `Set.apply(x)`.

Comment: `It might be a HashSet, but could be some other implementation.` - but on which factors depends returned type of Set? Before I think for `Set` default implementation is `HashSet`, for `IndexedSeq` - Vector and so on..