# what is the difference between HashSet and Set and when should each one be used?

Tags: scala

What is the difference between `HashSet` and `Set` and when should each one be used? Here's `Map` vs `HashMap`:

```
val hashSet = HashSet("Tomatoes", "Chilies")
val set = Set("Tomatoes", "Chilies")
set == hashSet // res: Boolean = true
```

Comment: You should have a glance at 

: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018659/the-difference-between-hashset-and-set-in-scala

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Set` is a trait. You can create an instance of a `Set` by invoking `apply` method of its companion object, which returns an instance of a default, immutable `Set`. For example:

```
val defaultSet = Set("A", "B")
```

`HashSet` is a concrete implementation of a `Set` which can be instantiated as follows:

```
val hashSet = HashSet("A", "B")
```

Have a look at the cite from "Programming in Scala" that explains the differences between various implementations:

> The `scala.collection.mutable.Set()` factory method, for example,
>   returns a `scala.collection.mutable.HashSet`, which uses a hash table
>   internally. Similarly, the `scala.collection.mutable.Map()` factory
>   returns a `scala.collection.mutable.HashMap`.
>
> The story for immutable sets and maps is a bit more involved. The
>   class returned by the `scala.collection.immutable.Set()` factory method,
>   for example, depends on how many elements you pass to it, as shown in
>   the table below. For sets with fewer than five elements, a special class devoted exclusively to sets of each particular size is used, to maximize
>   performance. Once you request a set that has five or more elements in
>   it, however, the factory method will return an implementation that
>   uses hash tries.

```
Number of elements  Implementation
0                   scala.collection.immutable.EmptySet
1                   scala.collection.immutable.Set1
2                   scala.collection.immutable.Set2
3                   scala.collection.immutable.Set3
4                   scala.collection.immutable.Set4
5 or more           scala.collection.immutable.HashSet
```

It means that for an immutable `Set` with 5 or more elements, both of your calls should return an instance of the same `Set` subclass.

The same goes for `Map`s. See [this](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/collections.html#17.3) link.

Comment: but even if I use a large set i.e  val largeSet = Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33) , still the result is:
largeSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 33, 9, 2, 22, 7, 3, 11, 8, 4)
and not HashSet as expected

Comment: But, largeSet.getClass() returns scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet

Comment: Try `print(Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33).getClass)` . This prints real class of Set and it prints `class scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet`

Answer (score 5):

When you call the `Set` or `Map` functions, you're actually calling the `.apply` method of the `Set` or `Map` object.  These are factory methods which choose appropriate types as documented in Rarry's answer.   In contrast, when you directly instantiate a HashSet, you're making the choice yourself.