# Scala Map vs HashMap

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

Is there a difference between a Scala `Map` and a `HashMap`? I am using the `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`.

Comment: [`HashMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap) is an implementation of [`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map). As you can see in their definitions `HashMap` is a class and `Map` is a trait.

Comment: In [_Programming in Scala, 1ed_](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/collections.html#17.3) (search for "_Default immutable map implementations_") they write that a `HashMap` is the default implementation for a `Map` with 5 elements or more.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`scala.collection.immutable.Map` is the interface for immutable maps while `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap` is a concrete implementation.

Creating with `Map()` or `Map.empty` gives a special empty singleton map, with `Map(a -> b)` with up to 4 pairs yields specialized classes for such small maps, and 5 and upwards gives you `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`

Comment: The author didn't specify scala.collection.immutable.Map or scala.collection.Map in the post. Does scala.collection.Map() also give you the same resulting Map implementations as scala.collection.immutable.Map()?

Comment: `scala.collection.Map.{empty, apply}` just delegates to the corresponding factory methods in the immutable `Map` companion. Note though that if you are explicitly using `scala.collection.Map` in a method signature for example, that will accept mutable maps as well as immutable. The `Map` automagically imported (by Predef) is `immutable.Map`.